# Lost FloatingActionButton State when change Portrait to Landsacpe

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I'm building an apps, that contain floatingactionbutton which I made with my own custom, when it pressed it shows 3 menu icons below it.

There are 2 problems:

1. When the orientation change to landscape, and we press floatingactionbutton it won't show instead of it will show when we press long, continue no 2
2. In current landscape it shows with long press like I said in no 1, and when we back again to portrait it need long press again to make it show

I've been trying some ways to make it fix, but it still doesn't work.

Here's the code and screenshot

[When portrait menu show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQxIu.jpg)

[When changing to landscape, menu icons are missing and need long press to make it show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFKne.jpg)

```
for floatingActionButton

    floatingActionButton: OrientationBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, Orientation orientation){
           return orientation == Orientation.landscape
           ? _buildMenu(context)
           : _buildMenu(context);
        },
      ),
```

_buildMenu() that call floatingActionButton

```
Widget _buildMenu(BuildContext context){
final icons = [ Icons.swap_vert, Icons.check_circle_outline, Icons.filter_list ];   
var nowOrientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;

var b = Container(
  child: LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints){
      return OverlayBuilder(
        showOverlayTrue: true,
        overlayBuild: (BuildContext overlayContext){
          RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
          final center = box.size.center(box.localToGlobal(const Offset(0.8, 0.8)));

           return new Positioned(
            top: Offset(center.dx, center.dy - icons.length * 35.0).dy,
            left: Offset(center.dx, center.dy - icons.length * 35.0).dx,
            child: new FractionalTranslation(
              translation: const Offset(-0.5, -0.6),
              child: FabIcons(
                icons: icons,
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    },
  ),
);}
```

To make it simple in viewing I put some code on github

OverlayBuilder Class https://github.com/ubaidillahSriyudi/StackOverflowhelp/blob/master/OverlayBuilderClass

Fabicons Class 
https://github.com/ubaidillahSriyudi/StackOverflowhelp/blob/master/FabIcons

Thanks so much to someone that could help it

Answer (score 0):

Happens because every time you change orientation, your FloatingActionButton rebuilds and loses state.

You should find a way to save the state of FabIcons widget.

---

Simple solution :

Constructing FabIcons widget with

```
 icons,
 iconTapped;
```

These variables should be saved in the Parent Widget, so every time you call `_buildMenu(context);` you pass in those variables

Comment: i've been try this
FabIcons(
   icons: icons,
   iconTapped: _selectedFab,
),

void _selectedFab(int index){
      setState(() {
        _lastSelected = 'FAB: $index';        
      });
  }

but still not work